# Extract numeric elements from a vector

Tags: r, regex, string, vector, numeric

I have a vector 'a' which has numeric and non-numeric elements. I want to extract the numeric elements from the vector and build a new vector. How do I do this?

So if a is:

```
a = c(15, 3, 44, "hello", 4, "NA")
```

I want to get a vector with four elements namely elements 15 3 44 and 4

Comment: Is your question now answerd? than please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = as.numeric(a)
b = b[!is.na(b)]
b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[grep('[0-9]+',a)]
#[1] "15" "3"  "44" "4"
```

Comment: you knows the different/advantage  between you and my post?

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

a <- c(15, 3, 44, "hello", 4, "NA")

as.numeric(a) %>% discard(is.na)
```

By default, R is going to convert `c(15, 3, 44, "hello", 4, "NA")` into a character vector (since you have a mixture of numerics and strings). So, you have to do the conversion first and remove the `NA`'s that get generated (you should see a warning message, too). The `purrr` idioms make what's happening very explicit to the reader, which is ideal since you're ultimately really programming for human comprehension (with computational comprehension a secondary goal).