# reading in csv file with character type variable but expand scientific notation readr

Tags: r, csv, character, scientific-notation, readr

I have a `csv` file with a variable (`id`). In `excel` when I check the format of the cells, some cells are type `general` and some are `scientific`:

```
#            id
# 1 ge189839898     #general format cell in excel
# 2   we7267178     #general format cell in excel
# 3     2.8E+12     #scientific format cell in excel
```

When I read the file into `R` using `read_csv`, it thinks that the column is `character` (which it is and what I want) but it means `2.8E+12` is also a character.

```
options(digits = 22, scipen = 9999)
library(tidyverse)
dfcsv <- read_csv("file.csv")
#where dfcsv looks like:
dfcsv <- data.frame(id = c("ge189839898",
                        "we7267178",
                        "2.8E+12"))
dfcsv
#            id
# 1 ge189839898     
# 2   we7267178    
# 3     2.8E+12
```

Is there a way to automatically read in the `csv` so that variables with mixed types are correctly identified so it would be return a `character` variable but scientific notation is expanded:

```
#               id
# 1    ge189839898
# 2      we7267178
# 3  2800000000000
```

I don't think `guess_max` is what I am after [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218646/write-csv-read-csv-with-scientific-notation-after-1000th-row). I would also prefer not to use `grep`/`sprintf` type solutions (if possible) as I think that is trying to fix a problem I shouldn't have? I found these problematic `id`s by chance so I would like an automated way of doing this at the reading in stage.

The cleanest solution is probably to go in to the `csv` file and make a conversion there but I want to do it through `R`.

Thanks

Comment: Columns in R cannot have mixed types. There's no way to have `readr` do what you want during import. You need to clean up the data after the fact. It would be better if you found a way to export the data from Excel where it didn't incorrectly reformat the data. Are you sure those ID values always are just filled with zeros? When switching to scientific notation I'd guess you are actually using the last few digits of precision would could be very important for IDs

Comment: You can find numeric values in your ID columns with this existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822643/extract-numeric-elements-from-a-vector

Comment: @MrFlick you are of course right with your first comment, something I naively overlooked.  In this case is my only solution to go back to excel? The link wont extract the numbers with `e` correctly as they have already been converted to character.

Comment: Well, If you don't go back to Excel I'm pretty sure you're going to lose information. If you're OK with that, then you can proceed in R. In the end the column is going to have to be character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
id <- c("ge189839898", "we7267178", "2.8E+12")
func <- function(x) {
  poss_num <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
  isna <- is.na(poss_num)
  x[!isna] <- format(poss_num[!isna], scientific = FALSE)
  x
}
func(id)
# [1] "ge189839898"   "we7267178"     "2800000000000"
```

Comment: this answers my question so thank you but I have naively overlooked @MrFlick 1st comment above so I asked the wrong question in a way. My `ids` are not just filled with zeros

Comment: I really don't understand what you're going for, then. You specifically stated *"return a character variable but scientific notation is expanded"*, meaning you were asking for the updated value to *still be strings*, which is what this does. I inferred that since you expressly wanted strings, you knew (or did not care) about the no-mixed-types thing. Over to you to figure out what you need here.

Comment: going back to excel is my only option here i think, thanks for the solution which I will use again!